# How to access nested tag of element in XML which have common name

Tags: javascript, html, xml, extjs

My XML somewhat looks like this:

```
<A> AID = "10"  BID = "20" CID = "30" DID = "40"
        <B> AB = "100" BB = "200" CB = "300" DB = "400"</B>
    </A>
    <C> EID = "10"  FID = "20" GID = "30" HID = "40"
        <B> EB = "10" FB = "10" GB = "10" HB = "10 </B>
    </C>
```

I wanted to access "B" tag element which is inside the "A" tag element.I am using `respXML.getElementsByTagName("B");` But in this case I am getting access of both the `B` tag. I want only access to `B` tag which only part of `A` tag not the `C` tag.

Comment: **That's not XML.**  For one, the `B` element is appearing in the start tag for the `A` element.  No XML tools or libraries can help unless you first fix your XML.

Answer (score 0):

With a fixed XML (see kjhughes' comment for that) I think you could use :

```
var childBs = document.getElementById('A').getElementsByTagName('B')
```

Basically you get all `A` elements and then all their `B` children and put them in the `childBs` variable.